# Google PHP API Client: CA cert error

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I'm attempting to interface with the Google PHP API client and I am having issues with the certificate provided by Google:

*Google error:*

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
Retrying with the CA cert bundle from google-api-php-client.
```

*PHP cURL error:*

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I had **no** problems whatsoever on a Linux box.  These errors are occuring on a Windows box.

I've tried a couple of different solutions:

[https://code.google.com/](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/FAQ)
[http://richardwarrender.com/](http://richardwarrender.com/2007/05/the-secret-to-curl-in-php-on-windows/)

but to no avail.

*PS:*

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

won't be acceptable ...

Comment: I am also having the same problem and also tried those two solutions but it keeps showing that error message! Guys anyone please help us! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Courtesy of rmckay at webaware dot com dot au:

Please everyone, stop setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false or 0. If your PHP installation doesn't have an up-to-date CA root certificate bundle, download the one at the curl website and save it on your server:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Then set a path to it in your `php.ini` file, e.g. on Windows:

```
curl.cainfo=c:\php\cacert.pem
```

Turning off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` allows **man in the middle (MITM) attacks**, which you don't want!

Comment: The other answers shouldn't be chosen.

Comment: Excellent solution! Has everything you need to know.

Answer (score -1):

\Google_Client::$io->setOptions(array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE));

Comment: generates possible security issues

Answer (score -4):

@sKophek is correct and I appreciate the help as I was struggling with this.  For those that prefer a touch more detail, here it is: (this is true, at least, for the 0.6.x version of the google-api-php-client)

1) \google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php

2) 
`private $curlParams = array (
      ...
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      ... );`

Comment: generates possible security issues